# Why is NHibernate swallowing a SQL error from a lazy-loaded collection?

Tags: nhibernate, exception, nhibernate-mapping

I've got an entity that maps a collection of components as follows:

```
<class name="TeacherResource" table="TeacherResource">
    <id name="TeacherResourceId">
        <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>

    <!-- irrelevant properties here... -->

    <bag name="HelpfulLinks" order-by="BogusColumnName">
        <key column="TeacherResourceId"/>
        <composite-element class="HelpfulLink">
            <property name="Href"/>
            <property name="Display"/>
         </composite-element>
    </bag>
</class>
```

At first I wasn't getting any data back for the collection, then I realized I had an incorrect column name in there for ordering the collection.  NHibernate doesn't throw an exception, but if you view the property in the debugger after the property is lazy-loaded, there is an `InnerException` defined that indicates the error.

Why would NHibernate trap this error?  I'm on .NET 4.0/NH 3.3.1.

[image: NHibernate error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, NHibernate never swallows Exceptions. Most likely that collection was loaded by data binding, in that case the data binding swallowed the exception.

Comment: Right on, it was indeed the data binding.  Interestingly, when I let the binding happen through the FormView/ObjectDataSource controls, the exception is swallowed.  If I bind manually, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate NEVER swallows Exception. Please, never expect that from NHibernate and never **suspect** NHibernate.

If you'd like, there is my advise is: Always start to suspect our (NHibernate consumers) code.

> Nobody is perfect, even NHibernate could have a bug *(and take a look
>   at the change log of the latest release, how many bugs was already
>   fixed)*.  But, collection mapping is so standard and so often used
>   part, that it could hardly keep the bug there.

From the set of information the question contains, it is hard to say where is the problem. Some ideas:

1) The collection `HelpfulLinks` is loaded lazily (as the snippet shows). It could happen, that it was never touched in runtime. The Exception *NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not initialize a collection* could be fired only in case, that there was some request to **initialize** it.

2) Just a guess, *very unlikely*, there could be some common handler in the solution on top of the DataLayer... converting Exceptions into something else (in fact swallowing them)

I do not have more ideas. But when

- I created form a scratch scenario with a `parent/child`,
- I followed your mapping (and set wrong column name into order-by,
- I recieved the exception in the moment I touched the `Children` collection.

Other words, please, try to observe the code more.